# Chrome extension does not receive response from content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to receive the video parameter `video` through `content.js` and send it to `popup.js`. `popup.js` sends greeting but cannot receive (probably) response from `content.js`

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), but id doesn't work. Sometimes it drops out this error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "UpCat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "UpCat"
  },
  "permissions": [
          "tabs"
        ],
  "content_scripts":[
    {
      "matches":["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
      "js":["content.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

**content.js**

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
  var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
      sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
      sParameterName,
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
      sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

      if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
          return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
      }
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      var link = getUrlParameter('v');
      sendResponse({video: link});
});
```

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, workOn);
  });

  function workOn (res) {
    console.log(res.video);
  }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>It haz to works</title>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="inner">
      Hello there
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to receive in `popup.js` response from `content.js`, literally `video` parameter, but it doesn't log anything.

Comment: 1) Your content script runs only if the tab was opened from a video page but it won't start if the the main page of youtube.com was opened first - because youtube is an AJAX-site that changes its contents and URL without server navigation. 2) You don't need a content script at all, just use `tabs[0].url` in your popup script and add `"https://www.youtube.com/"` to "permissions" key in manifest.json. 3) Just in case, the popup has its own devtools console accessible by right-clicking inside the popup then clicking "inspect".

Comment: @wOxxOm, thank you sir! That is exactly what I needed!